# where we can get java project file which is already under working project

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, netbeans-7, netbeans-8

I have done a sample application but i want to know that how to upload the file, for example is  android project have a file name .apk but in java application (using Jframe) in netbeans where we can get the pack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose Build > Build Project and if its a standard java project you will get a jar.